# Invalid bind expression type of RecordType for column of type String

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, compile-error

I have written below code and its causing me the error:

> Invalid bind expression type of RecordType for column of type String

Here is the code for reference

```
Map<Id, RecordType> caseMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>(
    [SELECT Id, DeveloperName
    FROM RecordType 
    WHERE SObjectType ='Case' AND Id='111111']
);
List<RecordType> recordTypes = caseMap.values();    
List<Case_Entitlement_Setting__mdt> EntitlementList = [
    SELECT Id,Record_Type__c,Category__c,Sub_Category__c,Entitlement_Name__c 
    FROM Case_Entitlement_Setting__mdt
    WHERE Category__c='BBB' AND Sub_Category__c='AAA' 
        AND Record_Type__c IN :recordTypes
];
```

The error coming on below line

```
AND Record_Type__c IN :recordTypes];
```

Comment: And the field type is...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the `IN :sObjectCollection` syntax when the field you filter on is a lookup. Otherwise, `IN` can only be used on a collection which matches the field type. For a text field, you need to match on a collection of `String`.

If you want to filter on the Ids, you can just filter on the `keySet`:

```
AND Record_Type__c IN :caseMap.keySet()
```

If you wanted to filter on, say, `DeveloperName`, you'd have to build the collection manually:

```
Set<String> recordTypes = new Set<String>();
for (Recordtype record : caseMap.values())
    recordTypes.add(record.DeveloperName);

... AND Record_Type__c IN :recordTypes
```